# Como forçar tamanho justificado?

Tags: html

#### Cenário exemplo

Tenho uma tabela gerada dinamicamente (php), e uma das colunas são placas de veículos.

O problema é que se dá uma **certa diferença conforme as letras e números são "maiores" e/ou "menores"**.

**Exemplo**: a letra `I` é mais estreita que a letra `W`, como o número `1` é mais estreito que o número `9` (claro que, depende da fonte também).

**Imagem do exemplo acima**:

[image: plalas]

---

#### Dúvidas

- O que gostaria é **deixá-los igualmente alinhados** (justificados!?), mas seria para um tamanho específico, e não entre todos os resultados (pois se não, iriam variar da mesma forma).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A título de curiosidade, outra opção, além da citada pelo amigo @wiliamvj seria vc usar uma fonte ***mono espaçada*** como a `monospace`, `consolas` ou `Inconsolata`

Essa tipo de *type-face* tem todos os carácteres com a mesma "largura", então o *kerning* é sempre igual não importa se é a letra I ou M a "largura" do caractere é sempre a mesma.

Veja o exemplo:

```css
body {
 font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div>
  iii-1111
</div>
<div>
  mmm-0000
</div>
```

**OBS:** Repare que no próprio *snippet*, mesmo sem executar os carácteres já aparecem alinhados :) *(a fonte do snippet é a Consolas)*

Para entender melhor o que é o ***kerning*** veja essa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**UpDate**

Ainda existe uma outra alternativa, apenas com CSS, mas [não funciona no IE/Edge](https://caniuse.com/#feat=font-variant-numeric) e só pode ser aplicada em números de fonts no formato `OpenType` *(OpenType é um formato de fonte que tem um suporte melhor dos sistemas, e funciona tanto no iOS quanto no Windows, [aqui vc pode ler mais](https://www.adobe.com/br/products/type/opentype.html))*

Para ajustar o texto só com CSS vamos usar a propriedade `font-variant-numeric` com o valor `tabular-nums`. [Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre essa propriedade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric). E resumindo a fonte precisa ser `.OTF` e só funciona com números, com texto normal não funciona!

**Nassa imagem foi usado `font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima

```css
body {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-family: fantasy; /* essa fonte aparentemente é .OTF no windows funciona */
}

p.tnum {
  font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
}

h4 {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}
b {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4><b>SEM</b> tabular-nums</h4>
  <p>1111111111</p> 
  <p>1234567890</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h4><b>COM</b> tabular-nums</h4>
  <p class="tnum">1111111111</p> 
  <p class="tnum">1234567890</p>
</div>
```

**Documentação oficial W3C:** https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#propdef-font-variant-numeric

Answer (score 4):

Você poderia usar o atributo `justify` (`text-align="justify"`), mas não é mais suportado no HTML5, então a única maneira que conheço é via CSS.

```css
#teste {
    width: 100%;
} 

p {
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 30%;
   text-align: justify;
}
#teste p:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="teste">
  <p>III - 1111</p>
  <p>WWW - 9999</p>
  <p>III - 1111</p>
  <p>WWW - 9999</p>
</div>
```